# Native executable scripts

Tags: python

There are python scripts like poetry and others that run natively without using python in the terminal.

What I mean with this is that instead of using

```
python script_name args
```

You use

```
script_name args
```

Is there a way of making native scripts like this other than using pyinstaller?

Comment: For what OS and shell are you looking for an answer?

Comment: You will need some kind of "installation" anyway.

Comment: If you want to install them with pip (which I presume you do not,) you can simply set `scripts` in the `pyproject.toml` for your build system. This will expose the scripts as native executables, even if they require python and pip to be installed.

If not, tools like poetry install themselves (on linux, at least) with a python build script, that does the same thing as the pip install with pyproject.toml would, just with curl or similar. Specifically, poetry uses this script: https://install.python-poetry.org/, which does still require python to be installed *somewhere*